# Access SSH and git sync by shell script

Tags: shell, ssh

We have a server ( hosting ) and we need to git pull every morning by manually.
We have tried to make it easier by a shell script file.

```
# /bin/bash

# add key
ssh-add /Users/ownner/Documents/keys/key.pem
# Access the server
ssh myusername@domain.com -p18181
# Wait and type the password

# Each to check
echo "Hello, I am in the server now"

# Move to the folder
cd www/folder1/public_html/wp-content/plugins

# Git pull
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -print -exec git -C {} pull \;
```

It works fine until adding the password.
But it is not working after that. The less of code work when I "exit" ssh.

I believe I have missed something.
FYI, We actually need to git pull on 6 folders. ( folder1, folder2, folder3, folder4, folder5, folder6 ). So we will use "for each" for the loop.

Can you please give us a tip how the cd, git pull work after login ( access ) the server?

Thank you,

Comment: Check `man ssh`. ssh foo@bar [command]. So you can append commands to the ssh-line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and put the last three command in a script, in the remote server, in an interactive SSH session.

You can make that script as elaborate as you need, finding folders, and executing git pull on each one.
The point is: once the script work on the remote server, then you can call it with a non-interactive SSH call:

```
ssh myusername@domain.com -p18181 /path/to/remote/script
```

Note: if you have a local public `key.pub`, you could copy it to the remote server `~myusername/.ssh/authorized_keys`, and you would *not* have to enter the `myusername` password anymore.